# How to populate a combo box from another combo box in the same form?

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox

Two comboBox and a table called MAINCATE is created.

I have a code , but stuck to determine what SQLQuery should i use to get the second combo box filled , determined by the first combo box.

I just need a little help on how to fill in the second combobox based on mainCate picked by the first combobox..

i need to do something like.. if combobox 1 mainCate is "Food" , then combo box 2 should show "Raw , cooked , fruits and vegetables"

This is what is inside of the MAINCATE table - 
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/Az8am.png)

And this is my code :-

```
DataSet ds1;
DataSet ds2;

public User()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}

private void User_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection();
    conn.ConnectionString = "Data Source=PEWPEWDIEPIE\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=master;Integrated Security=True";
    conn.Open();

    SqlDataAdapter daMain = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM MAINCATE", conn);
    ds1 = new DataSet();
    daMain.Fill(ds1, "Maincate");
    mainCatU.DisplayMember = "mainCate";
    mainCatU.ValueMember = "mainCate";
    mainCatU.DataSource = ds1.Tables["MAINCATE"];
    mainCatU.DropDownStyle = ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList;
    mainCatU.Enabled = true;

    SqlDataAdapter daSub = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT >What should i do here?<", conn);
    ds2 = new DataSet();
    daSub.Fill(ds2, "Subcate");
    subCatU.DisplayMember = "Subcat1";
    subCatU.ValueMember = "Subcat";
    subCatU.DataSource = ds2.Tables["MAINCATE"];
    subCatU.DropDownStyle = ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList;
    subCatU.Enabled = true;
    conn.Close();
}

private void mainCatU_SelectionChangeCommitted(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //have no idea if a code should be here..
}
```

or should i do something like this?

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select Subcat1,Subcat2,Subcat3,Subcat4 from MAINCATE where mainCate=@mainCate;", con);
```

=========================================

@philip -
putting this on page load repalcing my code above - it didnt work..

```
string result = mainCatU.SelectedItem.ToString();

            SqlDataAdapter daSub = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM MAINCATE where mainCate = " + result , conn);
            ds2 = new DataSet();
            daSub.Fill(ds2, "Subcate");
            subCatU.DisplayMember = "Subcat1";
            subCatU.ValueMember = "Subcat1";
            subCatU.DataSource = ds1.Tables["MAINCATE"];
            subCatU.DropDownStyle = ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList;
            subCatU.Enabled = true;
```

even tried

```
SqlDataAdapter daSub = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM MAINCATE where mainCate=@result", conn);
```

Comment: Do you even have to execute the SQL twice? Do both boxes have the same data source?

If so, just use ds1 on the second box aswell :)

Comment: If your getting the same data, then your selecting from the Maincate, which you should then think... "I am duplicating code here", so you can then just use the same datatable for both combo boxes.

Comment: sorry.. forgot to take that out when i wasnt even using it..

Comment: @MohdNasrulIwanFajaruddin so you are using the exact same data?

Comment: oo.. wow.. thanks for pointing that out.. 

ok , i've changed my code , now it runs on single data source..

but still , what do i put for the second combo box.. picture is there.. i need to do something like..

if combobox 1 mainCate is "Food" , then combo box 2 should show "Raw , cooked , fruits and vegetables"

Comment: @PhilipGullick - help?

Comment: @MohdNasrulIwanFajaruddin see my answer, you should be able to implement it then, I'm not aware of your table structure so I have just commented what to do.

Comment: table structure is in the link ..

[click here.. is the link](http://i.imgur.com/qR90Z2B.png)

Comment: it should work then, is your table called MainCate as well as a column? Try to implement my answer into your work.

Comment: table is called MAINCATE , while a column is mainCate , difference on letters though..

and the code didnt work..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, you don't need another sql query,because you already get all maincate records from database.You can simply use dictionary to store this records.

First define a `Dictionary<string,List<string>>`

Define it here(!)

```
 DataSet ds1;
 DataSet ds2;
 Dictionary<string,List<string>> allRecords = new Dictionary<string,List<string>>();
```

Then: (i edit your code)

```
SqlDataAdapter daMain = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM MAINCATE", conn);
ds1 = new DataSet();
daMain.Fill(ds1, "Maincate");

DataTable dt = ds1.Tables["MAINCATE"];
foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
{
   List<string> SubCats = new List<string> {
     dr["Subcat1"].ToString(), 
     dr["Subcat2"].ToString(),
     dr["Subcat3"].ToString(),
     dr["Subcat4"].ToString()
   };
 allRecords.Add(dr["mainCate"].ToString(),SubCats);
 mainCatU.Items.Add(dr["mainCate"].ToString());
}

mainCatU.DropDownStyle = ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList;
mainCatU.Enabled = true;
```

Then you need to handle mainCatU selectionchanged like this:

```
if(allRecords.ContainsKey(mainCatU.SelectedItem.ToString())) {
    subCatU.DataSource = allRecords[mainCatU.SelectedItem.ToString()];
}
```

Comment: i'll try this.. wait a sec.. :)

Comment: i get an error - Argument 1: cannot convert from 'object' to 'string'

Comment: all the errors are from here...

 dr["SubcCat1"], dr["SubcCat2"],dr["SubcCat3"],dr["SubcCat4"],
                };
                allRecords.Add(dr["mainCate"], SubCats);

Comment: try again,and if its possible can i see your mainCATU combobox picture?

Comment: now only this code left with the same argument..

allRecords.Add(dr["mainCate"], SubCats);

Comment: add ToString() after dr["mainCate"]

Comment: ok.. this one works.. but its stucked at Electronics(the first main category that it loads up with) , when i change to other other main category , it wont change the sub category.. (still stuck at electronic's sub category)

Comment: what are displaying main combobox? all values of maincat or just mainCate values? i assumed it contains just mainCate column values

Comment: Main combobox(mainCatU) displays only mainCate.. yep..

and we need to display the sub combobox(subCatU) the values of Subcat1~4 of what is picked by main combobox(mainCatU)

Comment: sub-cbox not showing anything..

since your DataTable dt = ds1.Tables["Maincate"]; , is it ok if the Maincate spelled like that? it isnt case sensitive?

and does the if (allRecords.ContainsKey(mainCatU.Text) goes into the form load or into the mainCatU_SelectedIndexChanged?

Comment: it must be your table name and must case sensitive you right.change it  to your actual table name,and Containskey method goes into mainCatU_SelectedIndexChanged

Comment: what are u using,WPF or winforms?

Comment: winforms.. 

if i put the constainkey into the mainCatU , the allRecords isnt detected.

Comment: then why you Add WPF TAG ?? i write this code for wpf,anyway...i change it for last time

Comment: and again , the Containskey isnt detected.. ..

error : the name "allRecords' does not exist in the current context.

Comment: define allRecords dictionary class level, i mean define it where you define datasets

Comment: type or namespace name var could not be found.

Comment: ok.. everything is done.. no errors now.. but combobox2 is still empty.

Comment: @Blam - tag fixed.. sorry for that again.. really sorry

Comment: im gonna do the macarena dance now just for selman... praise the lord.. :S

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what your looking for:

Fill the first combo box with your current code.

Then to fill the second combo box you need to hook up the first combo box selectionchangecommitted. However why not just use the standard event?

```
private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Here use if statements to capture what value is set
        if (comboBox1.SelectedIndex = 1)
        //If selected value is Vehicles
        {
            //Then SELECT * FROM MainCate WHERE MainCate = 'Vehicles'
            //This is possibly incorrect as I don't know how your DBTable is structured

            //Same code as before
            //Set this data to the second combobox
        }
    }
```

OK? So look into implementing this, if you want to refactor this you could, rather than using IF statements you could parametrise -

```
 string result = comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();

 SELECT * FROM MainCate WHERE MainCate = result
```

Obviously this won't compile so don't copy then paste it, then come back saying it doesn't work. It needs to be implemented like you did before, but rather than hardcode the result each time, use the parameter.

Personally I wouldn't have this all in one class, however you may prefer this way.

Comment: i did something like this.. but this doesnt work..
(on page load)

string result = mainCatU.SelectedItem.ToString();
            
            SqlDataAdapter daSub = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM MAINCATE where mainCate = " + result , conn);
            ds2 = new DataSet();
            daSub.Fill(ds2, "Subcate");
            subCatU.DisplayMember = "Subcat1";
            subCatU.ValueMember = "Subcat1";
            subCatU.DataSource = ds1.Tables["MAINCATE"];
            subCatU.DropDownStyle = ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList;
            subCatU.Enabled = true;

Answer (score -1):

ComboBox1, ComboBox2 -- you just want to populate ComboBox2 using ComboBox1 Select change. So, At first bind your ComboBox1. Then cretae an event for ComboBox1:

```
 private void ComboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
                {
                    string value1 = ComboBox1 .SelectedValue.ToString();
                    LoadComboBox2 ();        
                }
```

And Get your ComboBox1 selected value and use it to populate ComboBox2 .

```
private void LoadComboBox2 ()
        {
            DataRow dr;

            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=name;Initial Catalog=dbName;User ID=sa;Password=sa123");
            con.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select id,name from table where id=@ID", con);
            SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            sda.Fill(dt);

            dr = dt.NewRow();
            dr.ItemArray = new object[] { 0, "--Select--" };
            dt.Rows.InsertAt(dr, 0);

            ComboBox2 .ValueMember = "ID";

            ComboBox2 .DisplayMember = "Name";
            ComboBox2 .DataSource = dt;
            con.Close();

        }
```